# ArrayList contains NullPointer

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm using an `ArrayList<String>` and catching a `NullPointerException` on a method that checks if the `ArrayList<String>` holds a value. I'm passing an `int` to the method, then converting the `Integer` to a `String`.

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

public boolean doesContain(int i){
    return array.contains(Integer.toString(i));
}
```

Comment: On which line does it throw it?

Comment: It throws from the class I call doesContain

Comment: Could ypu publish the whole stack trace?

Comment: Please, provide the entire code. You might have a bug when initializing the variable `array`.

Comment: Is it the line that *calls* `doesContain`, or the return statement *within* `doesContain`?

Comment: Your problem must be elsewhere because this code looks fine

Comment: Gut feeling is that this is probably due to unboxing a `null` `Integer` object as the method argument at the call site, but it's impossible to say one way or the other without seeing the stack trace or the code that calls this method.

Comment: what is `array` in the method? in your code `array` is not a valid variable

Comment: As `array` seems to be a member variable it migth be set somewhere else in the code to `null`. In that case you would get an NPE at `return array.contains(Integer.toString(i));`

Comment: @JonK in the lin that calls.

Comment: The code above is just an example but the method is identical, the array name is totally different

Comment: @MaxiiPad In that case, the answer that popovitsj has provided is most likely correct. Would you mind posting the code that calls your method, and how the argument that you pass into it is acquired?

Comment: are you calling the doesContain Mehtod with the Wrapper Integer? if thats null you'll get a Nullpointer because auf auto-unboxing.

Comment: Most probably your class object is null which is causing NPE, Such guesses would not be posted if you would have posted the StackTrace :P

Answer (score 1):

The main difference from the point of view of the programmer between Integer and int, is that an Integer can be null, and an int cannot.

So if you call the method `a(int a)` like this:

```
Integer x = null;
a(x);
```

It will throw a NullPointerException, because it cannot convert a null value to an int.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is correct,

Either you are calling the method with an Integer which is null or your class which contain this method is null, and calling to yourClass.doesContain(1) raising a nullPointerException because "yourClass" is null.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

public boolean doesContain(int i){
try{
 return array.contains(Integer.toString(i));
         } catch (NullPointerException e){}

}
```

Comment: Tried this, still throws